# Cython: error adding complex[double] to double

Tags: python, operator-overloading, cython, complex-numbers

According to `libcpp/complex.pxd` adding `T` to `complex[T]` is supported:

```
    complex[T] operator+(complex[T]&, T&)
    complex[T] operator+(T&, complex[T]&)
```

But it doesn't work:

a.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++

cimport libcpp.complex

def f():
    libcpp.complex.complex[double](1,2) + libcpp.complex.complex[double](2,3) # ok
    libcpp.complex.complex[double](1,2) + 5. # Cannot assign type 'double' to 'complex[double]' 
    5. + libcpp.complex.complex[double](1,2) # Invalid operand types for '+' (double; complex[double])
```

setup.pyx:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = "demo",
    ext_modules = cythonize('a.pyx'),
)
```

Àny idea how to fix it?

Moving declaration

```
complex[T] operator+(complex[T]&, T&)
```

out of `cppclass` and changing it to

```
complex[T] operator+[T](complex[T]&, T&)
```

looks more legimate but still does not work.

Comment: I agree it's broken. I don't think there's a workable workround. Perhaps submit a bug report to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues?

Comment: @DavidW Done, issue [#1643](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1643)

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins That's the first time anyone's ever done it when I suggested they submit a bug report :)!

Comment: @DavidW haha :) Maybe one day the world will be a better place to live :)

Comment: AntonyHatchkins @DavidW I've submitted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43041856/cython-counter-tutorial-behavior) which provides sort of workaround yet raises new issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it working. See cython ticket  https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1643

It is a combination of 
moving

```
complex[T] operator+(complex[T]&, T&)
```

out of cppclass definition, changing it to

```
complex[T] operator+[T](complex[T]&, T&)
```

as suggested in the question and @DavidW's idea of `cimport *`